# angular 2 let not setting my variable as I expect

Tags: angular, typescript

Am trying to get an understanding of angular 2, and can't understand why some code wouldn't work for me.
In my component:

```
export class SelectListComponent implements OnInit {
fromList :string[];
toList : string[];

ngOnInit() : void{
let fromList =['A10', 'A20','A30', 'A35', 'A40'];
let toList =['A10', 'A20'];
}
```

I thought that I would then be able to loop through these arrays in my template, but the result was empty

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let t of toList"><td>hello{{t}}</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, if I change my component code to set the variables like so, the views display as expected.

```
ngOnInit() : void{
this.fromList =['A10', 'A20','A30', 'A35', 'A40'];
this.toList =['A10', 'A20'];
}
```

Could someone please explain why this is, and when I should use **let** to set the variable and when not, because this is not what I expected and I haven't found a reasonable explanation in the documentation.

Comment: `let fromList=` is creating a new local variable in the method, which the template cannot access. Did you mean `this.fromList=`?

Comment: `let` declares a new variable. When you use `let toList` in `ngOnInit`, you declare a new variable, different from the `toList` already declared as a class member.

Comment: Ah cheers, that makes total sense. I thought let was just used for assignment in the manner of old fashioned BASIC